# Delete previous version of files (in the form name_#.#.#-#.extension) on Linux

Tags: linux, version, delete-file

I have files which are named something like

```
foo_1.5.6-8.xyz
foo_1.5.6-9.xyz
foofoo-6.5.xyz
foofooofooo-8.7-1.xyz
foofooofooo-8.7-2.xyz
```

That is, the general form is **name_#.#.#-#.extension**, but some lack a "**-#**" and/or a "**.#**".

**EDITED:**

How can I delete all previous version of those files, retaining only ones with the highest versions? In the previous example, it would be:

```
foo_1.5.6-9.xyz
foofoo-6.5.xyz
foofooofooo-8.7-2.xyz
```

(I use Linux)

Answer (score 0):

As your `codesnippet` and explanation don't give much idea about the exact requirement, you may try with the below command and see if it does the thing:

```
rm foo*[0-9].xyz
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited my question, I apologize if it was unclear